# jQuery autocomplete close need to get values

Tags: jquery

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    selectFirst: true,
    autoFocus: true,
    source:
        function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/airports.ashx?q=" + request.term,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { value: item }
                    }));
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert("An unexpected error has occurred during processing.");
                }
            });
        }, select: function (event) {
        }
       , close: function (event, ui) {
           $("#txtfrom").val(ui.item.value);
       }
});
```

Comment: Could you describe your problem, perhaps in the form of a question?

Answer (score 0):

put this value in 'select' event , it will not available in 'close'

try this.......

```
, select: function (event) {
$("#txtfrom").val(ui.item.value);
        }
       , close: function (event, ui) {

       }
```

if you want in close then use like that.......
Declare value  outside autocomplete

var value='';

```
, select: function (event) {
value=ui.item.value;
        }
       , close: function (event, ui) {
           $("#txtfrom").val(value);
       }
```